# Java FX Filter table view

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to use a text field to filter through a table view, I want a text field (txtSearch) to search for the 'nhs number', 'first name', 'last name' and 'triage category'. I've tried implementing various solutions online and had no luck, I'm still new to all this so apologies if this was asked poorly. any help would be greatly appreciated, my code is below.

public class QueueTabPageController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private TableView<Patient> tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Patient, String> NHSNumberColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Patient, String> firstNameColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Patient, String> lastNameColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Patient, String> timeEnteredColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Patient, String> triageAssessmentColumn;

@FXML
private TextField filterField;

@FXML
private QueueTabPageController queueTabPageController;

private ObservableList<Patient> tableData;

// public static LinkedList<Patient> displayQueue;


/**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     * 
     * Initializes the table columns and sets up sorting and filtering.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        assert tableView != null : "fx:id=\"tableView\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLQueueTabPage.fxml'";

        NHSNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("nhsNumber"));
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("firstName"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("lastName"));
        timeEnteredColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("timeEnteredString"));
        triageAssessmentColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("triage"));

        // display the current queue to screen when opening page each time
        displayQueue(Queue.queue);

        // 0. Initialize the columns.
        //firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("firstName"));
        //lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("lastName"));

        // 1. Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all
        // data).
        FilteredList<Patient> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(tableData,
                p -> true);

        // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
        filterField.textProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    filteredData.setPredicate(Patient -> {
                        // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
                            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            // Compare first name and last name of every person
                            // with filter text.
                            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                            if (Patient.getFirstName().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                                return true; // Filter matches first name.
                            } else if (Patient.getLastName().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                                return true; // Filter matches last name.
                            }
                            return false; // Does not match.
                        });
                });

        // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList.
        SortedList<Patient> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        tableView.setItems(sortedData);

    }
```

I'm getting an error here (step 4):

```
(TableView.comparatorProperty());
```

and (step 5)

```
TableView.setItems(sortedData);
```

saying:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setItems(ObservableList) from the type TableView

Comment: "I've tried implementing various solutions online and had no luck." Please show what you have tried and explain what went wrong.

Comment: @James_D  I mainly tried this tutorial: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering but it just never fired when i typed in the text field.

Comment: The code in that tutorial runs fine for me.

Comment: @James_D I can't seem to implement it into my code, any help?

Comment: Just do the same thing that was done in the excellent tutorial you linked. If you can't get it to work, post the code you have tried. None of your code has anything at all to do with filtering the table.

Comment: @James_D my code is now error free however when i run and start typing in the text field there is nothing firing. This table view is a queue so patients are added and removed, could this be the issue as the table is initially empty unless a patient gets added?

Comment: As long as you just manipulate `tableData` and never call `tableView.setItems(...)` anywhere else, it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TableView` is defined as:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Patient> tableView;
```

So....

Try to put: `(tableView.comparatorProperty());`

instead of: `(TableView.comparatorProperty());`

and do the same with: `TableView.setItems(sortedData);`

I recommend you to change `tableView` for other more different than `TableView`, something like `patientTable`!

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Fixed that, error free but still not firing, could it be that the table is initially empty until a patient is added? so its not pre-populated? Sorry, new to all this.